# Sharepoint Online (Classic and Modern) Pages Pattern Search

Tags: search

We have Sharepoint Online and users can request sites of all types, while they can choose to have the classic or modern experience on them. We, also, have a media solution which users can use to generate embed code that they can then use to share their on any page. I have been tasked with finding pages on Sharepoint which contain either direct links to videos (e.g. multi-test.com/file) or embedded videos on Sharepoint pages (i.e. an embed code that will have src='multi-test.com/file').

I did some research online and this is my understanding, could you please let me know if I missed anything or correct me if I am wrong?

- Pages that the user creates on any type of site (hub, communication,...) will go in the Site Pages Library, no matter if it is a classic or modern site
- Modern Sharepoint pages are just a collection of web parts, so we can use PowerShell to get the JSON properties of the page and search for the URL provided
- I found a script at https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/ for extracting HTML content of Sharepoint modern pages, not sure if it is easier to follow the previous step or use this to do my searching

I have not found anything on how to get the HTML content of classic Sharepoint sites, would the approach for modern also work here?

I plan to do it the obvious way of searching through all subsites on the tenant and then look for the values I am interested in, would you think there is an easier/quicker/more effective way of doing it?

Regards,
Paul